# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL dialog.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm using wootique theme for wordpress and when try to add new post no shortcodes work and this error show in console screen `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` this error from `wootique\functions\js\shortcode-generator\dialog.php` and I'm try to show alert for testing if this JavaScript code work nothing showing then write `<script>` tag and i have error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: You need to show us more code to help you. For example show us the script at the specific row

Comment: @SuperDJ this is first line var framework_url = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\wootique\functions\js\shortcode-gen‌​erator\js'; but why the file extension is php and its included as javaScript in HTML? The source file is available on GitHub [link](https://github.com/jesusangel/wordpress-woocommerce/blob/master/wp-content/themes/wootique/functions/js/shortcode-generator/dialog.php)